# Converting Wattage to Temperature

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, power

Let us say you have an 8 watt source or heater, what is the highest temperature it can attain or be converted to?

I was asking in the context of transformer losses. At no-load, there is core loss.. if the temperature of the core is 50 Celsius. what minimum wattage of the iron core loss can produce that?

Comment: The problem is very-ill defined. We need (much) more information on your situation (what are you trying to heat, in what conditions, what is the environment, etc.........)

Comment: It's the context of transformer no-load core loss.. as your know.. transformers heat up even with zero load at the secondary. So what is the loss of wattage.. or what minimum wattage can cause 50 Celsius surface temperature?

Comment: Still far from being enough. If the losses happen in the core of the device, and you want us to compute an equilibrium temperature of the surface, we need at least to know the thickness of the material to be heated, its specific heat, the external conditions (outside ? what temperature ?), and probably the shape of your device if the convective transfer is to be accounted for. . Furthermore, I am not familiar at allwith the "no-load core loss" of a transformer, and maybe you'd have better luck in an electrical engineering stack exchange ?

Comment: I'm not asking for the specific surface temperature or heat. I just want to know the physics principle of how to convert wattage to heat or temperature. If you have say a light bulb of 8 watts.. how much heat or temperature can it attain?

Comment: I just want to make clear that your question has no answer. If your 8 watt light bulb is used  to light up a dark alley in eastern russia during a warm winter evening at -40C, it definitely wont reach the same equilibrium as if it was in the bahamas. Again, your problem is not well defined, and a Power is completely unsufficient to answer. Furthermore, you are confusing the basic notions of heat and temperature, which will make the discussion delicate. Heat is an energy transfer. Temperature is not

Comment: What's the right way to ask it then.. should one think in terms of BTU?

Comment: Please see comment number 3 in this discussion to see some examples of the minimum data that we would need. Also, keep in mind that the 2 example that you gave (light bulb and transformer) are VERY different from each other, and the calculations will lookvery different in each case. Physics is all about assumptions and simplifications, and we can not make the same ones for every problem

Comment: Maybe the following will make sense to you now... wattage to eddy current conversion to temperature... in induction cooker.. you used wattage to convert to heat...

Comment: Please, understand that heat and temperature are two completely different things. I can not understand your question until you nail this. If you want heat (and you assume that 100% of your "wattage" is used thermally), you just multiply this "wattage" of yours by the time elapsed, and you get the amount of heat produced in that time (which is a measure of thermal energy flow). If you want an equilibrium temperature, it is, as said before, a much more complex problem that requires loads more information.

Comment: I should have asked first about how to convert wattage to heat.. what is the basic formula.. why did you say just multiply the wattage by the time elapsed? Why would it produce heat? Formula?

Answer (score 1):

The temperature will rise until it's dissipating heat at the rate heat energy is being put into it. If it were so well insulated that the temperature would have to be 20,000K for it to dissipate at  that rate, then that is the temperature it would rise to!

Answer (score 0):

The temperature of an object is related to the total internal energy.  And you've supplied one thing that will affect the total energy of this item: the fact that there is a power input of 8 watts (8 joules per second).

Unfortunately, this doesn't tell you anything about the other flows of energy (heat loss).  If the object can easily lose that energy, then the temperature will remain very close to ambient.  If well insulated, the temperature will need to rise a lot to force the energy out.

An analogy would be to learn that a constructed pool will be pumped with water at a rate of 8 cubic meters per second, and asked how high the water will reach.  The answer depends on how the pool is constructed and how it holds water.

Likewise, the steady-state temperature of an object with a known power delivered to it depends on the object and its surroundings which control how the heat is removed.